# List within quotes of postgresql or other lines of code with quotes necessary?

Tags: python, postgresql, list, quotes, kafka-producer-api

This is a two part question.
I have a list that will have one item in the list

```
listA=["12345"]
```

i want to use the item in this list for my postgres look up. the code looks like this:

```
cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT first_name, actor_id FROM actor t WHERE  actor_id = 'listA'")
```

I want to call the number "12345" in my list but postgres gets confused if you dont have '  ' around the number. Even if I leave the '  ' out I still need to have the quotes around the whole statement. How can I get this to work when i need quotes? I think the proper name is nested quotes.

there are other points in time that i want to reference a list but the quote marks always come into play and stop this from happening. other times there will be multiple variable in the list.

Comment: you should take a look at --> http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#lists-adaptation

Comment: that seems to solve the first portion of my issue but when I'm not using postgres is there a way to use a list when quotes are needed?

Comment: that would be specific to the library and database that you choose to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ids = [10, 20, 30]

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = ANY(%s);", (ids,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically when adding in variables to my queries I will use the .format() function.

```
list = [12345]
query = ""SELECT DISTINCT first_name, actor_id FROM actor t WHERE  actor_id = '{0}'"
query = query.format(list[0])
```